# Diffie Hellman Key Exchange Security wrt the hardness of discrete Logarithm

Tags: diffie-hellman, key-exchange, discrete-logarithm, hardness-assumptions

Hi I am very new to this field and I was wondering how one would prove or disprove the following statements:

1) if the DH key exchange protocol is secure for a finite cyclic group G, then computing the DL is hard in G.

2) If computing the DL is hard in G, then the DH key exchange protocol is secure in G.

Answer (score 1):

(1) is easy; you just prove the [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) (which is logically equivalent):

```
If computing the DL is easy in a finite cyclic group G, then the
DH key exchange protocol is insecure in G
```

This is straight-forward.

(2) has no known proof.